# Merging files in Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, lambda-architecture

Nathan Marz in his book "[Big Data](http://www.manning.com/marz/)" describes how to maintain files of data in [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html) and how to optimize files' sizes to be as near native HDFS block size as possible using his [Pail](https://github.com/nathanmarz/dfs-datastores/blob/develop/dfs-datastores/src/main/java/com/backtype/hadoop/pail/Pail.java) library running on top of [Map Reduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

1. Is it possible to achieve the same result in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)?
2. Can I use [Google Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) instead of MapReduce for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage allows for composite objects, letting you store an object in multiple parts and combine them later up to a limit of 32 parts at once and 1024 constituent parts in total. This functionality is available in the API.

[Composite Objects and Parallel Uploads - Google Cloud Platform Developer's Guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects)

Comment: "Compose operations that yield component counts exceeding 1024 are not allowed. To add more objects to a composite object with a component count of 1024, you will first need to copy the composite object to a new object by downloading and then uploading the object." Strange limitation. Does it perform well? : )

Comment: It is indeed an odd limitation. I've only used this functionality to create composite files around 10-20GB in size. Performance has been really good at that scale, but I can't comment on how well it'll work for larger files.